# How do I determine the size of my HBase Tables ?. Is there any command to do so?

Tags: hadoop, export, hbase, bigdata

I have multiple tables on my Hbase shell that I would like to copy onto my file system. Some tables exceed 100gb. However, I only have 55gb free space left in my local file system. Therefore, I would like to know the size of my hbase tables so that I could export only the small sized tables. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
gautham

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try 
`hdfs dfs -du -h  /hbase/data/default/` (or /hbase/ depending on hbase version you use)

This will show how much space is used by files of your tables.

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 8):

for 0.98+ try `hadoop fs -du -s -h $hbase_root_dir/data/data/$schema_name/` (or /hbase/ for 0.94)

You can find hbase_root_dir from hbase-site.xml file of your cluster.
The above command will provide you summary of disk used by each table.

Answer (score 5):

use **du**

Usage: `hdfs dfs -du [-s] [-h] URI [URI …]`

Displays sizes of files and directories contained in the given directory or the length of a file in case its just a file.

Options:

*The -s option will result in an aggregate summary of file lengths being displayed, rather than the individual files.*

*The -h option will format file sizes in a "human-readable" fashion (e.g 64.0m instead of 67108864)*

Example:

```
hdfs dfs -du -h /hbase/data/default
```

output for me:

```
1.2 M    /hbase/data/default/kylin_metadata
14.0 K   /hbase/data/default/kylin_metadata_acl
636      /hbase/data/default/kylin_metadata_user
5.6 K    /hbase/data/default/test
```

Comment: I believe this is only showing the size of the file but not replicated size right ?