# size of HBase tables

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have used the command

`hdfs dfs -du -h  /hbase/data/default/`

as indicated here:
[How do I determine the size of my HBase Tables ?. Is there any command to do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729257/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-hbase-tables-is-there-any-command-to-do-so)
to view the sizes of the hbase tables. 
However, there are 2 numbers appearing in the output as in the following example:

`...
2.7 M    8.1 M    /hbase/data/default/rTblCM_opt
9.4 M    28.2 M   /hbase/data/default/rTblCM_std`

What is the meaning of these numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First number is the table size without replication, second number with replication. It seems that your replication factor in hadoop cluster is equal 3.